# Prove that family of periodic sets in integers form an algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that $\mathcal{E} = \{E \subset \mathbb{Z}: \exists d\in \mathbb{N}: E + d = E\}$ form an algebra.

- $\emptyset \in \mathcal{E}$ because $\emptyset + d = \emptyset$
- given $E_1, E_2 \in \mathcal{E}$ we have $E_1 + d_1 = E_1$ and $E_2 + d_2 = E_2$. Let x be least common multiple of $d_1$ and $d_2$. Then $E_1 \cup E_2 = (E_1 \cup E_2) + x$ and that is in $\mathcal{E}$.

How can I prove that the complement of arbitrary E is in $\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: Prove $(F+d)^\mathrm c = F^\mathrm c + d$ for $F ⊆ ℤ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's the claim that if $E$ has period $d$, then $E^c$ has period $d$.

Now, since $f(x)=x+d$ is a bijection on $\mathbb{Z},$ it's true for any set $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ that $f(A^c)=(f(A))^c$. Hence $E^c+d=(E+d)^c=E^c,$ since $E$ is periodic by assumption.